# Grid in style similar to orangina.eu?

Tags: javascript, grid, hover

I was looking to create a website and I was looking around for inspiration on websites and found the grid on the bottom on the page of www.orangina.eu and I absolutely love it. I have been looking for tutorials but haven't found one, yet. Could someone try to explain to me how this grid works (hover over one, all the other 'blocks' move with it).

I have been snooping around in their .js files to see if I could find anything related to this and I think I'm relatively close with this one(?) altough I do not fully understand it, I think it is.

```
            drawBlocks: function (t) {
            function e(t) {
                l.clearRect(0, 0, a.width, a.height), 1008 >= m ? (s = !0, "canvas-products" == o && (u = ["#eb4155", "#ffe118", "#ffea5c", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "4bbfe7", "#e23a19", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)"]), "canvas-home" == o && (u = ["rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "#ffffff", "#1a4e8b", "#ffa300", "#ffffff", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "#ffa300"])) : (s = !1, "canvas-products" == o && (u = ["#ffe118", "#eb4155", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "#ffea5c", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "4bbfe7", "#e23a19", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)"]), "canvas-home" == o && (u = ["rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "#1a4e8b", "#ffffff", "#ffa300", "#ffffff", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "#ffa300"])), d = [{
                    x: 0,
                    y: c
                }, {
                    x: .25 * a.width + c,
                    y: 0
                }, {
                    x: .5 * a.width,
                    y: v
                }, {
                    x: .75 * a.width,
                    y: 0
                }, {
                    x: a.width,
                    y: 0
                }, {
                    x: 0,
                    y: .5 * a.height
                }, {
                    x: .25 * a.width,
                    y: .5 * a.height + c
                }, {
                    x: .5 * a.width + v,
                    y: .5 * a.height
                }, {
                    x: .75 * a.width,
                    y: .5 * a.height - v
                }, {
                    x: a.width,
                    y: .5 * a.height
                }, {
                    x: 0,
                    y: a.height
                }, {
                    x: .25 * a.width + c,
                    y: a.height - c
                }, {
                    x: .5 * a.width,
                    y: a.height - 2 * c
                }, {
                    x: .75 * a.width - c,
                    y: a.height
                }, {
                    x: a.width,
                    y: a.height
                }], s && (d = [{
                    x: 0,
                    y: c
                }, {
                    x: .5 * a.width + c,
                    y: 0
                }, {
                    x: a.width,
                    y: v
                }, {
                    x: 0,
                    y: .25 * a.height
                }, {
                    x: .5 * a.width,
                    y: .25 * a.height
                }, {
                    x: a.width,
                    y: .25 * a.height
                }, {
                    x: 0,
                    y: .5 * a.height + c
                }, {
                    x: .5 * a.width + v,
                    y: .5 * a.height
                }, {
                    x: a.width,
                    y: .5 * a.height - v
                }, {
                    x: 0,
                    y: .75 * a.height
                }, {
                    x: .5 * a.width,
                    y: .75 * a.height
                }, {
                    x: a.width + c,
                    y: .75 * (a.height - c)
                }, {
                    x: 0,
                    y: a.height - c / 2
                }, {
                    x: .5 * a.width - c,
                    y: a.height
                }, {
                    x: a.width,
                    y: a.height
                }]);
                for (var e = 0; e < d.length; e++) p[e] = {
                    x: d[e].x,
                    y: d[e].y
                };
                if (void 0 != t && !s) {
                    var n = t;
                    t > u.length / 2 - 1 && n++;
                    var i = f[t].value * h;
                    if (p[n].x = p[n].x - i, p[n].y = p[n].y - i, p[n + 1].x = p[n + 1].x + i, p[n + 1].y = p[n + 1].y - i, p[n + 6].x = p[n + 6].x + i, p[n + 6].y = p[n + 6].y + i, p[n + 5].x = p[n + 5].x - i, p[n + 5].y = p[n + 5].y + i, null != g) {
                        var r = g;
                        g > u.length / 2 - 1 && r++;
                        var y = (1 - f[t].value) * h;
                        p[r].x = p[r].x - y, p[r].y = p[r].y - y, p[r + 1].x = p[r + 1].x + y, p[r + 1].y = p[r + 1].y - y, p[r + 6].x = p[r + 6].x + y, p[r + 6].y = p[r + 6].y + y, p[r + 5].x = p[r + 5].x - y, p[r + 5].y = p[r + 5].y + y
                    }
                    "canvas-home" == o && (p[2] = d[2], p[3] = d[3], p[7] = d[7], p[8] = d[8])
                }
                l.save(), l.scale((a.width - 40) / a.width, (a.height - 40) / a.height), l.translate(20, 20);
                for (var e = 0; e < u.length; e++) {
                    var b = e;
                    if (e > u.length / 2 - 1 && !s && b++, s && (e > 1 && b++, e > 3 && b++, e > 5 && b++), "canvas-home" == o && 0 == e) {
                        if (s) var w = l.createLinearGradient(0, 0, .5 * a.width, 0);
                        else var w = l.createLinearGradient(0, 0, .25 * a.width, 0);
                        w.addColorStop(0, "#09255c"), w.addColorStop(1, "#123c79"), l.fillStyle = w
                    } else if ("canvas-home" == o && 1 == e) {
                        if (s) var w = l.createLinearGradient(.5 * a.width, 0, a.width, 0);
                        else var w = l.createLinearGradient(.25 * a.width, 0, .5 * a.width, 0);
                        w.addColorStop(0, "#123c79"), w.addColorStop(1, "#1a4e8b"), l.fillStyle = w
                    } else l.fillStyle = u[e];
                    l.beginPath(), s ? (l.moveTo(p[b].x, p[b].y), l.lineTo(p[b + 1].x, p[b + 1].y), l.lineTo(p[b + 4].x, p[b + 4].y), l.lineTo(p[b + 3].x, p[b + 3].y)) : (l.moveTo(p[b].x, p[b].y), l.lineTo(p[b + 1].x, p[b + 1].y), l.lineTo(p[b + 6].x, p[b + 6].y), l.lineTo(p[b + 5].x, p[b + 5].y)), l.closePath(), l.fill()
                }
                l.restore()
            }

            function i() {
                var t = r.width() + 40,
                    e = r.height() + 40;
                a.width = t, a.height = e, m = t, 2 == window.devicePixelRatio && (a.width = 2 * t, a.height = 2 * e, a.style.width = t - 20 + "px", a.style.height = e - 20 + "px", a.style.top = "10px", a.style.left = "-10px")
            }
            var r = t,
                a = r.find("[data-id='canvas']")[0],
                o = r.find("[data-id='canvas']").attr("id");
            if (a.getContext) {
                var s = !1,
                    l = a.getContext("2d"),
                    u = [];
                "canvas-products" == o && (u = ["#ffe118", "#eb4155", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "#ffea5c", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "4bbfe7", "#e23a19", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)"]), "canvas-home" == o && (u = ["rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "#1a4e8b", "#ffffff", "#ffa300", "#ffffff", "rgba(5,29,81,.4)", "#ffa300"]);
                var c = 10,
                    h = 20,
                    d = [],
                    p = [],
                    f = [{
                        value: 0
                    }, {
                        value: 0
                    }, {
                        value: 0
                    }, {
                        value: 0
                    }, {
                        value: 0
                    }, {
                        value: 0
                    }, {
                        value: 0
                    }, {
                        value: 0
                    }],
                    g = null;
                r.hover(function () {}, function () {
                    g = null
                });
                var m = a.width;
                r.find(".block").each(function () {
                    var t = parseInt($(this).attr("data-id")),
                        i = f[t];
                    $(this).hover(function () {
                        n.to(i, .2, {
                            value: 1,
                            onUpdate: function () {
                                e(t)
                            }
                        })
                    }, function () {
                        g = t, n.to(i, .2, {
                            value: 0,
                            onUpdate: function () {
                                e(t)
                            }
                        })
                    })
                });
                var v;
                v = "canvas-home" == o ? 0 : c, i(), e(), $(window).resize(function () {
                    i(), e()
                })
            } else $(".block-product").click(function () {
                $(".overlay-products").show()
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

They written in a canvas (tag of html5) for the over animation... you must learn to write in a canvas.
For the images' animation they used a sprite and move it as frames.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Although I am not looking for how to animate the pictures inside of the canvas, I am merely looking for a way to make the canvas work like it is now. Could you give me any insight in that?